# UIPanGesture not moving individual view

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer, tinder

I am doing a iPhone project in Swift where on top of my homeScreen, I am adding multiple views in a stack.

My requirement is to be able to move each individual child view on top of the homeScreen like Tinder card swiping effect. I am using  `UIPanGesture` to achieve this so that the each individual view follows my finger on screen.

But my problem is that instead of the desired effect of moving only one screen all the stack of Views is moving together on my Home Screen.
I am stuck at this problem for the last 4 days. Kindly help me out.

Xcode Version 7.2.1 and Swift 2.1

Here is the code that moves the `UIView`:

```
//For creating each childView and adding UIPanGestureRecognizer to each childView

func configureInitialViewPlacement() -> Void {
    for var i:Int = cardsArray.count-1; 0 <= i; i--
    {
        let cardView = cardsArray[i]
       let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "beingDragged:")


        cardView.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)

        self.view.addSubview(cardView)

        var frame = CGRectZero
        var originalFrame = self.view.bounds
        originalFrame = CGRectMake(originalFrame.origin.x+10,originalFrame.origin.y+10 , originalFrame.size.width-20, originalFrame.size.height-20)

        frame.size.height = originalFrame.size.height
        frame.size.width = originalFrame.size.width - CGFloat((2*CGFloat(i)*paddingOffset))
        frame.origin.x = originalFrame.origin.x + CGFloat((CGFloat(i)*paddingOffset))
        frame.origin.y = originalFrame.origin.y + CGFloat((CGFloat(i)*paddingOffset))

        cardView.frame = frame

        cardView.setContentViewForCard(cardDataArray[i])

    }
}

// Method For gestureRecognizer

func beingDragged(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
    xFromCenter = Float(gestureRecognizer.translationInView(self.view).x)
    yFromCenter = Float(gestureRecognizer.translationInView(self.view).y)

    switch gestureRecognizer.state {
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
        self.originPoint = self.view.center
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
        let rotationStrength: Float = min(xFromCenter/ROTATION_STRENGTH, ROTATION_MAX)
        let rotationAngle = ROTATION_ANGLE * rotationStrength
        let scale = max(1 - fabsf(rotationStrength) / SCALE_STRENGTH, SCALE_MAX)

        self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.originPoint.x + CGFloat(xFromCenter), self.originPoint.y + CGFloat(yFromCenter))

        let transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(rotationAngle))
        let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, CGFloat(scale), CGFloat(scale))
        self.view.transform = scaleTransform
        self.updateOverlay(CGFloat(xFromCenter))
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
        self.afterSwipeAction()
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Possible:
        fallthrough
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Cancelled:
        fallthrough
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Failed:
        fallthrough
    default:
        break
    }
}


func afterSwipeAction() -> Void {
    let floatXFromCenter = Float(xFromCenter)
    if floatXFromCenter > ACTION_MARGIN {
        self.rightAction()
    } else if floatXFromCenter < -ACTION_MARGIN {
        self.leftAction()
    } else {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {() -> Void in
            self.view.center = self.originPoint
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0)
        })
    }
}

// For Right Swipe

func rightAction() -> Void {
    let finishPoint: CGPoint = CGPointMake(500, 2 * CGFloat(yFromCenter) + self.originPoint.y)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3,
        animations: {
            self.view.center = finishPoint
        }, completion: {
            (value: Bool) in
            self.cardsArray[0].removeFromSuperview()
    })
    delegateforcard.cardSwipedRight(self.cardsArray[0])
}

// For Left Swipe

func leftAction() -> Void {
    let finishPoint: CGPoint = CGPointMake(-500, 2 * CGFloat(yFromCenter) + self.originPoint.y)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3,
        animations: {
            self.view.center = finishPoint
        }, completion: {
            (value: Bool) in
            self.cardsArray[0].removeFromSuperview()
    })
    delegateforcard.cardSwipedLeft(self.cardsArray[0])
}
```

Let me know if you need more clarifications.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have also done the same in objective-c, You can get an idea from here,
Here is my code

```
            UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cardMoving:)];


-(void)cardMoving:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    xValueFromCenter = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self].x; // if right positive(+) value, negative for left
    yValueFromCenter = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self].y; // if swipe up positive(+), negative for down

    switch (gestureRecognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:{
            originalPoint = self.center;
            break;
        };
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:{
            CGFloat rotationStrength = MIN(xValueFromCenter / ROTATION_STRENGTH, ROTATION_MAX);
            CGFloat rotationAngel = (CGFloat) (ROTATION_ANGLE * rotationStrength);
            CGFloat scale = MAX(1 - fabs(rotationStrength) / SCALE_STRENGTH, SCALE_MAX);
            self.center = CGPointMake(originalPoint.x + xValueFromCenter, originalPoint.y + yValueFromCenter);
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotationAngel);
            CGAffineTransform scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scale, scale);
            self.transform = scaleTransform;
            [self updateOverlay:xValueFromCenter];
            break;
        };
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: {
            [self afterSwipeAction];
            break;
        };
        case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:break;
    }
}

-(void)updateOverlay:(CGFloat)distance
{
    if (distance > 0) {
        overlayView.Direction = GGOverlayViewDirectionRight;
    } else {
        overlayView.Direction = GGOverlayViewDirectionLeft;
    }
    overlayView.alpha = MIN(fabs(distance)/100, 0.7);
}

- (void)afterSwipeAction
{
    if (xValueFromCenter > ACTION_MARGIN) {
        [self rightAction];
    } else if (xValueFromCenter < -ACTION_MARGIN) {
        [self leftAction];
    } else { //for reseting the card
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                         animations:^{
                             self.center = originalPoint;
                             self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
                             overlayView.alpha = 0;
                         }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hites. But looks like my code is also the same just that it is in Swift. Unfortunately my code is not working as desired.  My main problem is that even though I am adding "panGestureRecognizer" to each individual view, it is not been recognised and the whole stack of views is moving together and not individually.

Comment: Actually problem may be.. that you have added all of your views,
you need to add first view only, and one is below,|
after swipe action you need to add your next view.